# Как правильно в параметры функции вводить указатели

Tags: c++, указатели

Не могу понять, почему указатель message не указывает на первый элемент строки, вроде в функции задал верные параметры... Хелп.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>


void GetText(char* text){
  int counter = 0;
  text = NULL;
  char* literas;
  char* temp = new char('A');
  while(*temp != '\n'){
    counter++;
    *temp = getchar();
    literas = (char*) realloc(text,counter*sizeof(char));

    if(literas == NULL){
      printf("Ошибка выделения памяти");
      exit(1);
    }

    text = literas;

    text[counter-1] = *temp;
  }


  for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
      printf("%c",*(text+i));
    } 

  delete(temp);

}





int main()
{
  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
  char* alphabet;
  char* key;
  char* message;
  alphabet = (char*) malloc(39*sizeof(int));

  if(alphabet == NULL){
    printf("Ошибка выделения памяти");
    exit(1);
  }

  for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++){ // Заполняем массив алфавитом ВЕРХНЕГО регистра
        *(alphabet+i-65) = char(i); //i-65 так как мы всё таки массив букв litera заполняем с нуля
    }

    for (int i = 48; i < 58; i++){ // Заполняем массив цифрами
        *(alphabet+i-22) = char(i);
    }

    *(alphabet+36) = ',';
    *(alphabet+37) = '.';
    *(alphabet+38) = ' ';

    printf("Введите сообщение:\n");
  GetText(message);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      printf("%c",*(message+i));
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Где тут c++? (10 символов)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Параметры функции являются ее локальными переменными. Если у вас, например, определен указатель `message` в вызывающей функции следующим образом

```
char *message;
```

и вы вызываете функцию `GetText` как

```
GetText( message );
```

то это можно представить следующим образом

```
void GetText( ){
    char *text = message;
    //...
```

То есть внутри функции изменяется отдельная локальная переменна `text`. Ее изменения внутри функции никак не затрагивают переменную `message`. Переменная  `message` как имела свое значение до передачи ее в качестве аргумента, так и будет иметь.

Решить проблему можно тремя способами. Можно объявить функцию, как возвращающую указатель, и этот указатель присваивать переменной `message` в вызывающем коде. Например,

```
char * GetText();

//...

char *message = GetText();
```

Можно объявить параметр как ссылочный тип. Например,

```
void GetText(char* &text);
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
//...

char *message = nullptr;

GetText( message );
```

И, наконец, можно объявить параметр как указатель на указатель. Например,

```
void GetText(char ** text);
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
//...

char *message = nullptr;

GetText( &message );
```

Естественно, тогда внутри функции вы этот указатель должны разыменовывать. Например,

```
literas = (char*) realloc( *text,counter*sizeof(char));
                          ^^^^^
// ...

*text = literas;
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам!

Comment: @ReCursia Не за что. Обращайтесь еще.:)

Answer (score 3):

Указатель `message` передается в функцию `GetText` *по значению*. Это значит, что никакие манипуляции над параметром `text` внутри функции `GetText` никакого влияния на значение `message` не окажут.

В `message` как был мусор с самого начала, так там и остался.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, а как можно исправить ситуацию?

Answer (score 0):

Вы указатель передаёте по значению, это позволяет функции и читать, и писать память по указателю, но сам указатель копируется и полностью защищён от изменения внутри функции. Вам надо передавать параметр по ссылке на указатель или по двойному указателю, тогда после возврата из функции указатель будет иметь то значение, которое присвоила функция. Или уж выделять память до вызова.